# wrapper.find() is throwing error in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

I'm trying to do a unit test on a Vue component. I'm getting an error when wrapper.find() is used.

Component is as given below:
snackbar.vue

```js
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      visibility: "snackbar/visibility",
      type: "snackbar/type",
      message: "snackbar/message"
    })
  },
  watch: {
    visibility(value) {
      if (value) {
        $("#snackbar").addClass("show " + this.type);
        setTimeout(() => {
          $("#snackbar").removeClass("show " + this.type);
          this.$store.dispatch("snackbar/close");
        }, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="snackbar">{{ message }}</div>
</template>
```

In the testing I want to get a div having snackbar as id using wrapper.find().

It's spec file:
snackbar.spec.js

```js
import SnackBar from '../../../src/modules/Common/_components/snackbar.vue';

import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('Snackbar component', () => {
  let store
  beforeEach(() => {
    let state = {
      isVisible: false,
      message: '',
      type: ''
    }

    let getters = {
      'snackbar/visibility': (state) => state.isVisible,
      'snackbar/type': (state) => state.type,
      'snackbar/message': (state) => state.message
    }

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        snackbar: {
          state,
          getters
        }
      }
    })
  })

  it('renders the correct markup', () => {
    let wrapper = mount(SnackBar, { localVue, store })
    let snackbar = wrapper.find('#snackbar');
    
    // some test code related to snackbar
  })
})
```

The log is as given below:

cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run

30 05 2018 18:18:57.847:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/

30 05 2018 18:18:57.849:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency

30 05 2018 18:18:57.855:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS

30 05 2018 18:18:58.293:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket UwfYAt7yHauyEGfNAAAA with id 26585183

Snackbar component
    ✗ renders the correct markup
        undefined is not a function (evaluating 'vNodes.findIndex(function (node) { return vNode.elm === node.elm; })')

```
    webpack:///node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:2887:48 <- index.js:145115:83  
    filter@[native code] 

    removeDuplicateNodes@webpack:///node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:2887:0 <- index.js:145115:23  

    findVNodesBySelector@webpack:///node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:2917:0 <- index.js:145145:30  

    findVnodes@webpack:///node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:2934:0 <- index.js:145162:30  

    find@webpack:///node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:2982:0 <- index.js:145210:27  

    find$$1@webpack:///node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:3272:0 <- index.js:145500:19  

    webpack:///test/unit/specs/snackbar.spec.js:38:32 <- index.js:142013:32
```

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.622 secs / 0.009 secs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with an old version of vue-test-utils. findIndex is not supported in IE, so we have removed findIndex from recent versions.

If you cannot update to the latest @vue/test-utils, you can add a findIndex polyfill before you run the tests—https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of @vue/test-utils which is 1.0.0-beta.16. As you've said that it is problem with IE, I thought it might be same with PhantomJs. So, I changed karma-phantomjs-launcher with karma-chrome-launcher and changed browsers array in karma.conf.js to 'Chrome'. Now, wrapper.find() works fine. So, is it right to do it or anything else should be done?